# PostgreSQL formatting timestamps

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, timestamp

I create table employees in PostgreSQL with 4 columns (`employee_id`, `first_name`, `last_name` and `date_of_birth`, all `NOT NULL`, and `employee_id` is the primary key).

Now, I have 704 records in my table and add more with a for loop. For this purpose I wrote this code:

```
DO
$do$declare
   r text;
BEGIN 
   FOR i in 705..50000 LOOP
      r = i::text||'days';
      INSERT INTO employees(employee_id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth)
         VALUES (
            i,
            'ww'||i::varchar,
            'ss'||i::varchar,
            '1980-01-01 00:00:00'+interval r
         );
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

but it gives me an error in using r. How do I repair this code?

Comment: It would be nice to know the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_test()
RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
declare  r text;
begin 
 for i in 705..750 
 loop
    r := i::text||' days';

    insert into employees(employee_id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth)
     values (i,
          'ww'||i::varchar,
          'ss'||i::varchar,
          '1980-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP + r::interval);
 end loop;
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

More explanation: your code is `i::text || 'days'` which will output `705days` instead of `705 days` as we want. Another place is `'1980-01-01 00:00:00' + interval r`, I'll change it to `'1980-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP + r::interval` for more clearly.

I hope this will help you.